# notifyDataSetChanged() weird behavior on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, notifydatasetchanged

I am implementing a chat window. It is working fine on 4.2 Emulator but weird acting on 2.3.3 Emulator. I have implemented a custom `Adapter` extending `BaseAdapter` to populate the `ListVIew`. `ListView` is refreshing the list respecting `items` base on who's message to display. Emulator 4.2 is refreshing the list as desired but on 2.3.3 list refreshes the with last selected item. Here is the code for my `getView` function.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View chatItem = convertView;
    if (chatItem == null) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) //TODO: Change it to arrayListChat.getUpdater
            chatItem = ((LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_me, parent, false);
        else
            chatItem = ((LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_support, parent, false);

        ChatListItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ChatListItemViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textViewChat = (TextView) chatItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewChat);
        chatItem.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ChatListItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ChatListItemViewHolder) chatItem.getTag();
    viewHolder.textViewChat.setText(arrayListChat.get(position).getMessage());
    return chatItem;
}
```

Link for the images

Emulator 4.2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfOgJ.png

Emulator 2.3.3
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tLCT.png

Thanks

Comment: Where isthe screenshot?

Comment: you can upload the screenshot on http://imgur.com and paste a link here..

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare nice help :)

Comment: try call refreshDrawableState() on your list view when you call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter

Comment: @Mafro34 same thing happening.